Firestore snpashot alway null Unity
I try to read a document that exists in the firestore, but it always doesn't. I also checked the rules and they are good.
_checkOffer = true;
var document = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("limitedOffer").Document("car");
var checkIfExistDocument = document.GetSnapshotAsync();

yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => checkIfExistDocument.IsCompleted);

try
{
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = checkIfExistDocument.Result;
    //_limitedCarOfferData = snapshot.ConvertTo<LimitedCarOfferData>();
    Debug.Log(snapshot);
    Debug.Log(snapshot.Exists);
}
catch
{
    _limitedCarOfferData = null;
}



I tried to change the rules, I tried to create another document, but so do

have you checked if firebase was properly initialized in your unity project?

Yes, I checked. If I do build and put it on the phone it works, but in the editor it doesn't.

Please post your initialization code and the contents of your Console logs.
